# SQL logic: two tables (group by?)

Tags: sql

I have two tables, a table of movies (mt, the primary table), and a table listing where those movies are available (st, the secondary table).  For each mt record, there are multiple st records.  I need a query which will join the records, and allow me to run queries on *both* tables.  I currently use an inner join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY " + orderField + @") AS RowNum,
           mt.ID AS mt_ID,
           mt.title AS mt_title,
           [...]
           st.ID AS st_ID,
           st.title AS st_title,
           [...]
    FROM mt AS mt 
    st AS st
    INNER JOIN sttable AS st on mt.ID =st.ID
    WHERE st.title=@variable <> 0 AND mt.title = @variable
)    
    as DerivedTableName
    WHERE RowNum between 
    ((@pageIndex - 1) * @pageSize + 1) and @pageIndex*@pageSize
```

The problem with this is that I need to be able to loop through mt using RowNum and pageIndex, and the query returns more than one record for each movie (for example, if there are 8 records for a particular movie, 8, not 1, records are returned).  I have tried using GROUP BY, but the problem with that is that it will not allow me to perform queries on fields in the subordinate table (st).

Any help as to the appropriate logic would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve there. The query is made to return all the rows that have a corresponding mt and st. You want to know how many record of st for each mt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that does a `GROUP BY` in the derived table subquery so you get only one row per movie title, and calculate the `ROW_NUMBER()` from that.

Then join the result of the derived table to `st` again in the outer query.  There will still be multiple rows per movie title, but the `RowNum` will repeat so you can filter for your `@pageIndex` correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY " + orderField + @") AS RowNum,
           mt.ID AS mt_ID,
           mt.title AS mt_title,
           [...]
    FROM mt AS mt 
    INNER JOIN sttable AS st ON mt.ID =st.ID
    WHERE mt.title = @variable
    GROUP BY mt.ID
) mt1
INNER JOIN sttable AS st1 ON (mt1.ID = st1.ID)
WHERE mt1.RowNum BETWEEN 
    ((@pageIndex - 1) * @pageSize + 1) AND @pageIndex*@pageSize;
```

You'll have to loop over the result of the outer query in your display code and begin a new row of output whenever the value `RowNum` changes.  This is a pretty obvious technique.

If you instead want to do something like MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, this is tricky in Microsoft SQL Server (I assume you're using Microsoft).

See blogs like http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html that describe use of the `FOR xml PATH ('')` trick.

PS: Your sample SQL query didn't make sense given your verbal description, so I did my best to write something sensible.  No guarantees it matches your schema.

---

Re your comment:  I don't think you need to order by any column of `st` inside the subquery.  I intended there to be no columns from `st` included in the select-list of the subquery.  The only reason there's an instance of `st` joined in the subquery is to restrict the rows of `mt` to those that have matching rows in `st`.  But the `GROUP BY mt.ID` makes sure there's only one row per row of `mt` (actually since this is SQL Server and not MySQL you'll need to name all the `mt` columns of the select-list in the `GROUP BY` clause).

---

Re your second comment:

> I want to first display mt rows that have corresponding st records that have been most recently added

You can add other columns to the grouped query if you use grouping functions.  For instance, the latest `date_added` per group of `mt` is `MAX(st.date_added)`, and you can add this column to the subquery.

However, don't use `ORDER BY` in the subquery.  There's seldom any reason to sort a subquery, since the order may be altered anyway by using the subquery result in the JOIN or other operations you'd use a subquery in.

You should sort in the outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY " + orderField + @") AS RowNum,
           mt.ID AS mt_ID,
           mt.title AS mt_title,
           [...] -- other mt.* columns
           MAX(st.date_added) AS latest_date_added
    FROM mt AS mt 
    INNER JOIN sttable AS st ON mt.ID =st.ID
    WHERE mt.title = @variable
    GROUP BY mt.ID, -- other mt.* columns
) mt1
INNER JOIN sttable AS st1 ON (mt1.ID = st1.ID)
WHERE mt1.RowNum BETWEEN 
    ((@pageIndex - 1) * @pageSize + 1) AND @pageIndex*@pageSize
ORDER BY mt1.latest_date_added DESC, st1.date_added DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm now using a query similar to the one you suggested, but the problem I'm having is that I need to be able to sort st in the inside query, but when I try to do so I am told that the column I have selected to sort by is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  If I add the column to the GROUP BY clause, then the query once again starts returning multiple rows for each mt entry.

Comment: OK -- Yes -- I've got the mt columns working properly (they are in the select list and the GROUP BY clause), but how can I sort by a field in st?  For example, I have a field in st called "date_added", and I want to order the mt results by st.date_added (i.e., I want to first display mt rows that have corresponding st records that have been most recently added).  Would I put the ORDER BY st.date_added code in the outer query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to have both this:

```
FROM mt AS mt 
  st AS st
```

and this:

```
INNER JOIN sttable AS st on mt.ID = st.ID
```